# Upgrading a project from VS.NET 2003 to VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Will it be difficult ? The program is written in C.

Answer (score 1):

Save a backup copy of the project (just in case), then just open it in Visual Studio 2008. The upgrade will run automatically. Usually, there aren't any major problems, though it depends on your code. If there are problems, you will be able to see the upgrade log. Then, build your program to check if there were any errors introduced. If not, then run it and test it.